Функция в signIn.then() выполняется до завершения самого signIn NextAuth
Ожидание: по клику на кнопку сначала вызывается signIn, чтобы войти через GitHub, а затем вызывается ServiceSignIn, в котором создается сессия.
<button onClick={() => {
    signIn("github").then(() => ServiceSignin());
}}/>

export async function ServiceSignIn() {
    await createSession(id);
}

Но еще до открытия страницы GitHub со входом, а тем более еще до завершения авторизации, сессия создается. Как такое может быть?

Мы не знаем что у вас в signIn

@AlexeyTen это функция, предоставляемая библиотекой next-auth

Мы всё ещё не знаем что эта функция делает и почему вы ожидаете что она должна зарезолвить промис после авторизации. Где это написано?

@AlexeyTen А для чего мне его резолвить? Я ожидаю, что после авторизации, будет вызван метод ServiceSignin.

Где в документации написано что signIn резолвится после авторизации?

@AlexeyTen вы хотите сказать, что signIn резолвиться, т.е. выполняется then, еще до окончания авторизации?

Вообще, главная проблема заключается в том, чтобы после отработки signIn вызвать какую-то другую функцию. Получилось достичь такого только через костыль, а именно - указать callbackUrl на страницу, на которой и вызовется нужная функция.
<button onClick={() => {
    signIn("github", { callbackUrl: "/gateway" });
}}/>

'use client'

import { ServiceSignin } from "@/services/ServiceAuthActions";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Gateway() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const Actions = async () => {
            await ServiceSignin();
        }

        Actions();
    }, []);
}

