Как выполнить ряд действий после завершения авторизации через signIn Next Auth?
Нужно выполнить несколько действий, ну или просто вызвать функцию, после завершения авторизации через signIn от next-auth с провайдером по типу GitHub. Как это сделать?

Покажите, как это сейчас выглядит у вас в коде. А так должно быть что то вроде auth().then((res) => /*  тут ваш код*/)

@SwaD вот здесь пытался так сделать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1600411/434766. В ответе я написал вариант, в котором задуманное работает, но это явно костыль.
